# Has anyone expercience with decoupeld Magento with Node.js serving the frontend?

Tags: node.js, rest, magento, e-commerce, headless

I was wondering if anyone has tried using Magento just as a backend and use Node.js for serving the frontend. Its seems much more flexible and more practical for multistores.

Comment: I'm wondering the same. Has anyone tried it?